# Percent sign after a fraction? Convert to percent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, arithmetic, fractions, percentages

Isn't it wrong to write the following with only the percent sign? Instead of $100 \%$?

> The change in height as a percentage is
> $$
> \frac{a - b}{a} \% \tag 1
> $$
> where $a$ is the initial height and $b$ is the final height.

Because if $a=10$, $b=5$ we have
$$
\frac{10-5}{10}\%=\frac{1}{2} \% = 0.5 \frac{1}{100} = 0.005
\quad \text{what?!}
\tag 2
$$

If we convert a decimal number to percent we multiply it by $100$ and add the percent sign. We have $1\%=\frac{1}{100}$, so with $100 \%$ we multiply the number by $1$, i.e.
\begin{align}
\frac{10-5}{10} \cdot \color{blue}{1}
&=
\frac{10-5}{10} \cdot \color{blue}{100 \%}
=
\frac{5}{10} \cdot 
\color{blue}{100 \frac{1}{100}}
=\frac{1}{2} \cdot 
\color{blue}{100 \frac{1}{100}} \tag 3
\\
&=0.5\cdot \color{blue}{100 \frac{1}{100}}
=50 \color{blue}{\frac{1}{100}} = 50 \color{blue}{\%} \tag 4
\end{align}
So, shouldn't we instead write $(1)$ as
$$
\frac{a - b}{a} 100 \% \quad ? \tag 5
$$

Comment: Yes definitely. In fact you can always multiply by $100\%=1$ without changing the number :)

Comment: Personally, I would get in the habit of avoiding percent signs altogether similar to how I'd avoid using degrees for angles rather than radians... Unfortunately, a large number of elementary texts seem to prefer these notations despite their frustrations...

Comment: As to your question... if you are asking what $\frac{10-5}{10}$ is when written as a percentage... you are correct that $\frac{10-5}{10}$ is a ratio of numbers who when evaluated is equal to $0.5$ which when **converted to** a percentage would be $50\%$.  On the other hand, if we were to ask to take $\frac{10-5}{10}\%$ and **interpret it as** a percentage and **convert from** a percentage to a more traditional ratio... we would indeed have $\frac{10-5}{10}\% = 0.5\% = 0.005$.  Take careful note of the distinction between converting **to** a percentage and converting **from** a percentage

Comment: As for whether whoever originally wrote the formula you cite made a mistake.. yes.  I would go further to say that the *description* is also a mistake.  The change in height is simply $a-b$ (*where presumably $a$ was the original height and $b$ is the new height, possible special consideration for negative values*)... no ratio involved.  The *ratio of the difference in height compared to the old height* is what would be $\frac{a-b}{a}$

Comment: "I would get in the habit of avoiding percent signs altogether similar" Hear!  Hear!

Answer (score 1):

In what concerns exclusively the use of the percentage sign $\%$, it is simply a shorthand notation for $1/100$, so e.g. *five percent of a population of $n$ elements* is equivalently expressed as the amount $$n \cdot 5\%=n\cdot \frac{5}{100} =\frac{n}{20}= 0.05 n$$

So it is true that
$$\frac{10-5}{10}\%=\frac{1}{2}\%=0.005$$
although it certainly doesn't correspond to the percentage representation of the ratio $\frac{1}{2}$, which would of course be $50\%$.

Answer (score 1):

"Isn't it wrong to write the following with only the percent sign? Instead of 100%?"

It depends on what you want to say.

There's nothing *wrong* with saying $a=10$ and $b=5$ and  $\frac {a-b}{b}\% = \frac 12\% = 0.005$ *if that is what you want to say*.

But you are correct.  That is *not* what the author wanted to say.

The author wants to say that if something was originally $10$ feet and it ended up as $5$ feet then it *SHRUNK* by $50\%$ or that it grew by *negative* $50\%$.

And the formula for that is:---- well lets think it out.

If $a$ is the starting and $b$ is the ending then the *absolute* change is $b-a$.

In comparison to what it was, the thing has grown by the following fraction $\frac {b-a}a$ from what it was.

And in terms of percentages that is $\frac {b-a}a\cdot 100\%$.  In this case it grew by $-50\%$.

The formula $\frac {a-b}a\%$ would mean something else entirely.  It'd be hard to put it in practical terms to come up with a question that that would be a solution for.

....

Note:  If the question was what *was* the *original* value as a precent of the final value.  Then if $a=$ the *final* value and $b=$ the *original* value then $\frac {a-b}a 100\%$ would be the correct formula.  If it *started* at $5$ feet and grew to $10$ feet then it grew by what percentage of the final result.  Well it grew $5$ feet which is $50\%$ of $10$.

Answer (score 1):

Caution: some authors improperly write expressions like $\dfrac{a-b}a\%$ with the meaning that the value should be thought of as percents. In this case, the percent sign should not be taken for a factor. $\dfrac{a-b}a(\%)$ would be safer.

Leaving this on the side, IMO $$\dfrac{a-b}a\%$$ should rarely occur because there are no common reasons to multiply a fraction by one percent (if this really occurred, I would certainly write $0.01$ instead of $\%$). On the opposite, an evaluation like

$$\frac{a-b}a=5\%$$ makes perfect sense.

I also think that $$\dfrac{a-b}a100\%$$ is ugly/superfluous and would puzzle people.